# for statement keeps put first empty value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get only checked checkbox values
so I used `for` statement.

It goes well if I check from the first

but if I check from second It put empty value in array.

even I set this contidion, it still put empty value.

> if (document.getElementsByName("check")[i].checked == true)

what is problem?

[image]

**js**

```
var arr_downloadName = new Array();
  var chekced_download = 0;
  $(".compress").click(function () {
            var size = document.getElementsByName("check").length;
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (document.getElementsByName("check")[i].checked == true) {
                    arr_downloadName[i] = document.getElementsByName("check")[i].value;
                    chekced_download++

                }
            }
        });
```

**html**

```
 <tr>
                <td id="10Mb.dat"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='10Mb.dat'
                                         data-url="https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x10800.jpg"/>File10MB
                </td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="100mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='100mb.bin'
                                          data-url="http://speedtest-ny.turnkeyinternet.net/100mb.bin"/>File100MB
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="500MB.test"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='500MB.test'
                                           data-url="http://nl.altushost.com/500MB.test"/>File500MB</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="1000mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='1000mb.bin'
                                           data-url="http://speedtest.tele2.net/1GB.zip"/>File1GB</td>
            </tr>
  <button class="btn btn-primary compress">압축하기</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're not specifying an element at index `0` (or previous indexes). Thus, if you try and add an element into an empty array at index `1` (which happens when you check the second checkbox) then you're array needs to put in an `empty` value in at index `0` so that it can add an element into index `1`.

A solution to this would be to use `.push` which appends items to the end of your `arr_downloadName` array:

```js
let chekced_download = 0;
$(".compress").click(function() {
  let arr_downloadName = [];
  var checkElem = document.getElementsByName("check");
  var size = checkElem.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (checkElem[i].checked == true) {
      arr_downloadName.push(checkElem[i].value);
      chekced_download++

    }
  }
  
  console.log(arr_downloadName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td id="10Mb.dat"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='10Mb.dat' data-url="https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x10800.jpg" />File10MB
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="100mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='100mb.bin' data-url="http://speedtest-ny.turnkeyinternet.net/100mb.bin" />File100MB
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="500MB.test"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='500MB.test' data-url="http://nl.altushost.com/500MB.test" />File500MB</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="1000mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='1000mb.bin' data-url="http://speedtest.tele2.net/1GB.zip" />File1GB</td>
</tr>
<button class="btn btn-primary compress">압축하기</button>
```

As a side note, while it isn't needed, I recommend that you add a variable such as `checkElem` which holds your collection of elements. Then, instead of having to re-query the DOM each time you can instead just reference your element list, which will improve overall performance.

Also, I noticed that you're not making use of jQuery to it's fullest. Instead, you can get all the elements with the name `check` which are checked using a different selector:

```
$("[name='check']:checked")
```

and then `.map` all the elements selected to an to their values:

```js
$(".compress").click(function() {
  let arr_downloadName = $("[name='check']:checked").toArray().map(function(e) {
    return e.value;
  })

  console.log(arr_downloadName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td id="10Mb.dat"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='10Mb.dat' data-url="https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x10800.jpg" />File10MB
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="100mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='100mb.bin' data-url="http://speedtest-ny.turnkeyinternet.net/100mb.bin" />File100MB
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="500MB.test"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='500MB.test' data-url="http://nl.altushost.com/500MB.test" />File500MB</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="1000mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" name='check' value='1000mb.bin' data-url="http://speedtest.tele2.net/1GB.zip" />File1GB</td>
</tr>
<button class="btn btn-primary compress">압축하기</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if (document.getElementsByName("check")[i].checked != null)
```

Comment: with your way it puts every check values ["10Mb.dat", "100mb.bin", "500MB.test", "1000mb.bin"]

Answer (score 2):

seems your code will work. you are using incorrect variable to put the values in array. Make minor correction. i.e use 'chekced_download' instead of i as below, to push the values in array

```
arr_downloadName[chekced_download] = document.getElementsByName("check")[i].value;
```

Comment: so simple and correct! could you explain why chekced_download? because i thinks [i] also same as chekced_download?

Comment: i is generic iterator where as chekced_download is getting incremented only when condition is true. i use to keep on increment and by the time condition is true it is ahead of actual index of selected value

Answer (score 1):

Checked is a very sneaky HTML attribute

where if checked looks like

```
<input checked />
<input checked="checked" />
```

and produces `true` result

where if NOT checked looks like

```
 <input />
```

which produces NULL - because there is no checked attribute. So check for the checked check. *McCheck Check!*

```
  .checked != null
```

Hence you getting empty value.

Comment: with your way it put every check values ["10Mb.dat", "100mb.bin", "500MB.test", "1000mb.bin"]

Comment: ok then change the != null to null.. im not sure what your code looks like. but if its null do not add to array.. if its not null add to array